# Grouping list with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have list with files creating dates. I need to group this dates by day name, day, month and year.

```
    def group_datetime(self, list_of_files_creation_time):
        df1 = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_files_creation_time)
        df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'Day': ['Mon']})
        grouped_list = df1.groupby(pandas.cut(df1[list_of_files_creation_time], df2['Day'])).agg({'Day': })

        return grouped_list
```

In 'list_of_files_creation_time' I have:

```
<class 'list'>: ['2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-12-Mon 11:26', '2018-11-12-Mon 11:26']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_files_creation_time = ['2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-16-Fri 10:29', '2018-11-12-Mon 11:26', '2018-11-12-Mon 11:26']
print(list_of_files_creation_time)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_files_creation_time, columns=['date_init'])

df1 = df1.join(df1.date_init.str.split(' ', expand=True))
df1 = df1.rename(columns={0: 'date', 1: 'hour'})
df1 = df1.join(df1.date.str.split('-', expand=True))
df1 = df1.rename(columns={0: 'year', 1: 'month', 2: 'day', 3: 'day_of_week'})

df_month = df1.groupby('month').first()
df_day = df1.groupby('day').first()

print(df1)
print(df_month)
print(df_day)
```

Comment: Does it fit to your need ? if not please give me the expected output

Comment: What does the.   .firsr do at the end of group by?

Comment: it returns the first line for each group, it is the same as .agg('first').

Comment: Most of the time, you will use .sum(), the get the sum of the values associated for each group. But in your case you don't have any value associated to your dates

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'm not the questioner BTW, just looking to learn from the experts!

Comment: Thank u! It's very useful for me!